# Why are the offenses against Blessed Virgin Mary are called blasphemies instead of sin?

Tags: catholicism, sin, virgin-mary, blasphemy, unforgivable-sin

> There are five types of offenses and blasphemies committed against the Immaculate Heart of Mary:
>
> 1. Blasphemies against the Immaculate Conception.
> 2. Blasphemies against Her Perpetual Virginity.
> 3. Blasphemies against Her Divine Maternity, in refusing at the same time to recognize Her as the Mother of men.
> 4. The blasphemies of those who publicly seek to sow in the hearts of children indifference or scorn, or even hatred of this Immaculate Mother.
> 5. The offenses of those who outrage Her directly in Her holy images.

[Top 5 Sins Against the Immaculate Heart of Mary](http://www.vcatholic.com/articles/top-5-sins-against-the-immaculate-heart-of-mary/)

**Why are the offenses against Blessed Virgin Mary are called blasphemies instead of sin?**

Looking for Catholic Foundational Teaching and explanation on blasphemies against the Blessed Virgin Mary.

Comment: Consider this reply to something you said to another person.  "Yeah? Well, your mom!"  Is that not offensive?

Comment: Can anyone explain the downvote please on my answer below? all my citations are based on CCC and Sis.Lucia revelations which are a Church approved "private revelations".

Answer (score 4):

Because blasphemy can relate to that which is very sacred to God also, as it is written:

> **Revelation 13:6 (DRB)** And he opened his mouth unto blasphemies against God, to **blaspheme** his **name,** and **his tabernacle,** and **them that dwell in heaven.**

Cf. Jude 1:8, 10.

Answer (score 4):

**Why are the offenses against Blessed Virgin Mary are called blasphemies instead of sin?**

Blasphemies touch that which is sacred, and the Most Holy Virgin Mary is the Mother of Our Lord Jesus Christ. She is the Sacred Tabernacle that nurtured Jesus for 9 months while he was in the womb of Mary.

> While etymologically blasphemy may denote the derogation of the honour due to a creature as well as of that belonging to God, in its strict acceptation it is used only in the latter sense. Hence it has been defined by Francisco Suárez as "any word of malediction, reproach, or contumely pronounced against God: (De Relig., tract. iii, lib. I, cap. iv, n. 1). It is to be noted that according to the definition blasphemy is set down as a word, for ordinarily it is expressed in speech, though it may be committed in thought or in act. Being primarily a sin of the tongue, it will be seen to be opposed directly to the religious act of praising God. **It is said to be against God, though this may be only mediately, as when the contumelious word is spoken of the saints or of sacred things, because of the relationship they sustain to God and His service.**
>
> Blasphemy is a sin against the virtue of religion by which we render to God the honour due to Him as our first beginning and last end. St. Thomas says that it is to be regarded as a sin against faith inasmuch as by it we attribute to God that which does not belong to Him, or deny Him that which is His ([II-II.13.1](http://www.newadvent.org/summa/3013.htm#article1)). - [Blasphemy (Catholic Encyclopedia)](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/02595a.htm)

Mary is the Mother of God and Jesus is not to be denied a Mother.

Honour Jesus with reverence and love and one will honour his Mother. Insult the Blessed Virgin Mary and one insults her Son.

The [Immaculate Conception](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immaculate_Conception) is a privilege given to Mary directly from Almighty God and as such sins against the Mary's Immaculate Conception are considered blasphemous in the eyes of the Church since it touches that which is sacred in our holy religion.

Answer (score 0):

*Why are the offenses against Blessed Virgin Mary are called blasphemies instead of sin?*

**Biblical References & Explanation :**

> " And he opened his mouth unto blasphemies against God, to blaspheme his name, and **"his tabernacle"**, and them that dwell in heaven."(Revelation13:6 Douay Rheims)

What it means by the word **"his tabernacle"**?

The article below explained or pointed to ***Mary as the Tabernacle of God or the Word the Logos made flesh.***

> **Readings:**
>
> • 2 Sm 7:1-5, 8b-12, 14a, 16
>
> • Ps 89:2-3, 4-5, 27, 29
>
> • Rom 16:25-27
>
> • Lk 1:26-38
>
> “**Hail! tabernacle of God and the Word**. *Hail! holy beyond all holy ones. Hail! ark gilded by the Holy Ghost. Hail! unfailing treasure-house of life.”*
>
> These words from the ancient *Akathist hymn*, a great sixth-century song of praise for the mystery of the Incarnation, poetically summarize the Marian themes in today’s readings. **The Theotokos—the Mother of God—is the dwelling place of God, the “container of the Uncontainable God,” and “the womb of God enfleshed.”**
>
> Many of the early Church fathers spoke of Mary as the new ark of the covenant. **“Mary, in whom the Lord himself has just made his dwelling,”** the Catechism remarks, “is the daughter of Zion in person, the ark of the covenant, the place where the glory of the Lord dwells” (par. 2676). The ark of the covenant, described in Exodus 25, was a gold-plated wooden chest containing holy objects, including some manna, Aaron’s rod, and a copy of the covenant between God and Israel (Heb. 9:4-5). Its lid, the mercy seat, was made of gold and adorned with two cherubim, representing the throne of God.
>
> **For a long time the ark was kept in a mobile tabernacle.** Eventually, as we hear in today’s first reading, King David desired to build a permanent house, or temple, for the ark. In responding to David, the Lord made clear that the only one who could build an everlasting house for God is God himself; he promised to eventually “raise up” an heir who would establish an everlasting throne and kingdom.
>
> **“Hail! O you who have become a kingly Throne. Hail! O you who carries Him Who carries all! Hail, O Star who manifests the Sun. Hail! O Womb of the Divine Incarnation!”**
>
> Mary, created without sin, finding favor with God, and accepting in faith the call of the Lord, became a living, breathing ark of the covenant. “Full of grace, Mary is wholly given over to him who has come to dwell in her and whom she is about to give to the world” (CCC 2676). ***As God once dwelt in the tabernacle among a nomadic people, he now comes to dwell, through a singular woman,*** among men—pilgrims journeying toward their heavenly home. “For the first time in the plan of salvation and because his Spirit had prepared her, **the Father found the dwelling place where his Son and his Spirit could dwell among men” (CCC 721).**
>
> *“Behold,” exclaims the Akathist hymn*, **“heaven was brought down to earth when the Word Himself was fully contained in you!** Now that I see Him in your womb, taking a servant’s form, I cry out to you in wonder: Hail, O Bride and Maiden ever-pure!” During Christmas we cry out in wonder at the work of God and the faith of his mother.

https://www.catholicworldreport.com/2017/12/23/hail-mary-tabernacle-of-god-and-the-word/

Therefore, ***Mary is the Tabernacle of God*** and the Book of Revelation clearly stated that it is a *"blasphemy"* to blaspheme the *"Tebernacle of God"* which is *Mary the Mother of the Logos the Theotokos.*

Answer (score -2):

Catholic Foundational Teaching acknowledging Mary as ***"All-Holy"*** therefore *an offense on the Blessed Virgin Mary is really and certainly classified as blasphemy.*

> 493 The Fathers of the Eastern tradition call the Mother of God ***"the All-Holy" (Panagia)***, and celebrate her as "free from any stain of sin, as though fashioned by the Holy Spirit and formed as a new creature".138 By the grace of God Mary remained free of every personal sin her whole life long. 
>   "Let it be done to me according to your word. . ."
>
> 721 Mary, ***the all-holy ever-virgin Mother of God***, is the masterwork of the mission of the Son and the Spirit in the fullness of time. For the first time in the plan of salvation and because his Spirit had prepared her, the Father found the dwelling place where his Son and his Spirit could dwell among men. In this sense the Church's Tradition has often read the most beautiful texts on wisdom in relation to Mary.101 Mary is acclaimed and represented in the liturgy as the "Seat of Wisdom."
>
> 2030 It is in the Church, in communion with all the baptized, that the Christian fulfills his vocation. From the Church he receives the Word of God containing the teachings of "the law of Christ."72 From the Church he receives the grace of the sacraments that sustains him on the "way." ***From the Church he learns the example of holiness and recognizes its model and source in the all-holy Virgin Mary;*** he discerns it in the authentic witness of those who live it; he discovers it in the spiritual tradition and long history of the saints who have gone before him and whom the liturgy celebrates in the rhythms of the sanctoral cycle.

*Therefore, based on the Catholic Church Teaching and Doctrines the Blessed Virgin Mary is "All-Holy" by virtue of God's singular priveleges and graces bestowed on Mother Mary for Her Mission in the Church as the Mother of the Redeemer and also the Mother of all the Redeemed.*

With regards to the 5 five types of offenses and blasphemies committed against the Immaculate Heart of Mary as revealed to Sis.Lucia, this sin are not only blasphemy but described to as *"unforgivable sin".* This five offenses or five grave sins to the Theotokos cannot be forgiven by the Justice of God and requires reparation.Sis.Lucia describes why Mary reveals this five blasphemy in order for all the souls who committed this type of offenses rendered by God as the *"unforgivable sin"* can be appease and atone.

> In 1929, in the apparition of Tuy which is the final fulfillment of Fatima, Our Lady will conclude the extraordinary manifestation of the Holy Trinity with these striking words: ***"So many are the souls which the justice of God condemns for sins committed against Me that I come to ask for Reparation. Sacrifice yourself for this intention and pray."*** These words are so strong that several translators took the liberty of diluting their meaning.

See, this five grave offenses are not only blasphemous but it is the ***"unforgivable sins".***

> *"A little act of Reparation"* to save the greatest sinners. ***Yes, Our Lady affirms sadly, many souls are lost because of their scorn, their blasphemies against Her*** . . . Thus, giving us the example of loving our enemies, She Herself intervenes, because She alone can still save these monsters of pride and ingratitude who have revolted against Her. As **"Mother of Mercy and Mother of Pardon,**" as we sing in the Salve Mater, She intercedes for us before Her Son: may the filial devotion of faithful souls, and the Communions of Reparation offered on the Five First Saturdays to console Her outraged Heart, be accepted by Him in Reparation for the crimes of sinners. Our Lady prays that He deign to accept this "little devotion," and take into account this "little act of Reparation" to Her Immaculate Heart, and deign to grant pardon in spite of everything, to the ingrates and blasphemers, all the poor souls who have had the audacity to offend Her------***She, His Most Holy Mother!*** [The Fatima Crusader](http://www.catholictradition.org/Mary/fatima1b.htm)

The five revealed offenses to the Blessed Virgin Mary the ***"Mother of Mercy and Mother of Pardon"*** is unforgivable because Mary instead of punishing the souls who committed this sins simply ***"cried tears even tears of blood"*** in many of the approved Marian Apparitions.

The ***"cries of tears even tears of blood of the Theotokos"*** for all the souls condemned by the Justice of God moved the Sacred Heart of Jesus.The words of Jesus reveals to Sis,Lucia the following in order to console Her Mother's Sorrowful & Immaculate Heart.

> **"(*Words of Jesus*) See, My daughter, the motive for which the Immaculate Heart of Mary inspired Me to ask for this little Reparation, and in consideration of it, to move My mercy to pardon souls who have had the misfortune of offending Her. As for you, always seek by your prayers and sacrifices to move My mercy to pity for these poor souls.**"

*Explanation on the Sins against the Holy Spirit:*

> ***"The sin against the Holy Spirit."*** Here we have one of the principal themes of the Message of Fatima: since God has decided to manifest more and more His great design of love, which is to grant all graces to men through the mediation of the Immaculate Virgin, it seems that their refusal to submit with docility to what God wills is the fault which most gravely wounds His Heart, and for which He no longer finds in Himself any inclination to pardon. This sin seems unforgivable, because for Our Savior there is no crime more unpardonable than to despise His Most Holy Mother, and **"to outrage Her Immaculate Heart, which is the Sanctuary of the Holy Spirit. This is committing "the blasphemy against the Holy Spirit, which will not be forgiven in this world or in the next."** [The Fatima Crusader](http://www.catholictradition.org/Mary/fatima1b.htm)

The Justice of God condemned this sins because it is a direct offense to the Most Holy Trinity. 
Mary is the chosen daughter of God whom God chooses in eternity to be dwelling place of the Logos and the Holy Spirit.

> 721 Mary, the all-holy ever-virgin Mother of God, is the masterwork of the mission of the Son and the Spirit in the fullness of time. **For the first time in the plan of salvation and because his Spirit had prepared her, the Father found the *"dwelling place"* where his Son and his Spirit could dwell among men.** In this sense the Church's Tradition has often read the most beautiful texts on wisdom in relation to Mary.101 Mary is acclaimed and represented in the liturgy as the "Seat of Wisdom."
>
> In her, the "wonders of God" that the Spirit was to fulfill in Christ and the Church began to be manifested:

*As the Book of Kings stated* "the Highest Heavens cannot contain God whom She carried in Her Womb"*.*

*Panagia (Greek: Παναγία, fem. of panágios, pan- + hágios, the All-Holy; pronounced Greek pronunciation: [panaˈʝia]) in Medieval and Modern Greek, also transliterated Panayia or Panaghia, is one of the titles of Mary, the mother of Jesus, used especially in Eastern Catholicism and Orthodox Christianity.*

[image]

[The Wondrous Icon of Panagia Prodromitissa](https://www.johnsanidopoulos.com/2012/07/wondrous-icon-of-panagia-prodromitissa.html)

**Theological Support that the five offenses listed above against Mary is the "unforgivable sin".**

Mary is acknowlege by Church Tradition as the Mother of Mercy and in Fatima Apparition Her direct and urgent message is repentance "Penance,Penance,Penance."

When a christian not only reject the calling of the Mother of Mercy the instruments used by God to call on all the Redeemed to repentance but instead commits any of the five grievious offenses. The Catechism of the Catholic Church defined it as the "unforgivable sin".

> 1864 "Therefore I tell you, every sin and blasphemy will be forgiven men, but the blasphemy against the Spirit will not be forgiven."136 There are no limits to the mercy of God, ***but anyone who deliberately refuses to accept his mercy by repenting, rejects the forgiveness of his sins and the salvation offered by the Holy Spirit***.137 Such hardness of heart can lead to final impenitence and eternal loss.

Mary is the Spouse of the Holy Spirit the instruments of God in calling all people to repentance as seen in the Fatima Apparition. Rejecting Mary the Mother of Mercy is rejecting the Holy Spirit actions thru Her Maternal Mediation imploring all souls to seek repentance.

Comment: Can you give us one source, just one and not your own wording that ***these blasphemies are "unforgivable sins"***: St. Thomas Aquinas, Catechism of the Catholic Church, Canon Law or a Doctor of the Church? Please, just one quote is all I ask. You seem to make these conclusion that are based on your own perspective and not those of the Church. These blasphemies are serious sins, but to say they are the "unforgiveable sins" is going out on a limb. I would not state that unless I could source it out with proper theological support.

Comment: I can give words of Popes(St.Pius XII), I can give you words of Doctor of the Church like St.Luguori and I can give words of Saints like St.Montfort & St.Kolbe but for simplicity and direct quote I will give the very words of Jesus Himself who knew before he leave this earth Her Mother's actions & dignity will be attack. ..."anyone who publicly attribute the works of the Holy Spirit to the devil is the Unforgivable Sin" (Matthew12:32). Now, ask yourself, is Mama Mary's actions like the approved Marian Apparition the work of the Holy Spirit?

Comment: Ken have you read Mama Mary's own words to Sis.Lucia why She is asking the Five Saturday Devotions as reparation because the Justice of God condemns the 5 offenses listed above. if those offenses are condemned are they not unforgivable? Here's is the own words of Mama Mary as revealed " "So many are the souls which the justice of God condemns for sins committed against Me that I come to ask for Reparation." is this words not clear that Mary had seen souls go to hell because of the 5 mentioned blasphemous offenses?http://www.catholictradition.org/Mary/fatima1b.htm

Comment: I want a clear quote and not your own interpretation into your answer, please, that these offences are *unforgiveable*. Please prove your statements.

Comment: @KenGraham this is the explanation on the cited article "This sin seems unforgivable, because for Our Savior there is no crime more unpardonable than to despise His Most Holy Mother, and "to outrage Her Immaculate Heart, which is the Sanctuary of the Holy Spirit. This is committing "the blasphemy against the Holy Spirit, which will not be forgiven in this world or in the next."(this is not my word it is in Matthew12:32)http://www.catholictradition.org/Mary/fatima1b.htm

Comment: Any quote from [The Fatima Crusader](http://www.catholictradition.org/Mary/fatima1b.htm) must source it's material quotes which it does not do.

Comment: @Ken Graham then one must use prudential judgement and discernment if the site of CatholicTradition.org has a credible refutation. It will be your personal judgement over the credibility of the people behind that site.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90759/discussion-between-ken-graham-and-marian-agustin).

Comment: From the Catechism of Pope St. Pius X, Chapter 3 ("The Sacraments"), Question 22 under "Sacrament of Penance": The sacrament of Penance has the power of remitting all sins no matter how numerous and great they are, provided it is received with the requisite dispositions.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Jesus is the one who revealed the Five Unforgivable Sins.The Church Sacrament of Penance has the power to forgive but not all sins as Jesus described the "Unforgivable Sin" in Matthew12:32. Mary is the Mother of Mercy and for us to commit any of the Five Sins enumerated is rejecting the "Mercy being offered to us by God thru Mary the Mother of All the Redeemed." CCC1864 is tied up with Hail Mary as it stated "at the hour of our death the Blessed Virgin Mary is interceding for all souls to seek & accept the Mercy of God" and it is further magnified in the "Fatima Decade Prayer".